# Mail command contains cc and from in linux

Tags: linux, bash, email

Am getting -aFrom:sender@example.com contains invalid character ':'

```
 reciver1@example.com main recipient
    reciver2@example.com should be in cc
    sender@example.com should be sender  
    echo "This is the message body" | mail -s "This is the subject" -c reciver1@example.com   reciver2@example.com -aFrom:sender@example.com
```

Comment: -a is to add a file as an attachment.

Comment: then what should be the correct mail command for above requirement ?

Comment: https://linux.die.net/man/1/mailx Look at the -t flag.

Answer (score 0):

mailx might work for you this way:

```
value="someValue"

mailx -s "This is the subject" -t <<EOF
To: receiver1@example.com
From: sender@example.com
Cc: receiver2@example.com
Bcc: receiver3@example.com
X-Extra-Flag: ${value}

This is the message.
EOF
```